# ¿Cómo cargar un archivo excel que contiene imágenes en C#?

Tags: c#, excel, bitmap

El problema surge desde un archivo excel que le llega al cliente el cual contiene una gran cantidad de información que incluyen imagenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya conseguí hacer la carga desde un archivo excel con las siguientes funciones:

```
    private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cargar_excel(txt_hoja.Text, txt_archivo, lista);    
    }

    private void cargar_excel(string hoja, DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.TextBoxX txt_archivo, DataGridView lista)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hoja))
        {
            ToastNotification.Show(this, "Escriba el Nombre de la hoja a leer", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
            return;
        }
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "Archivos de Excel (*.xls;*.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx";
        dialog.Title = "Seleccione el archivo de Excel";
        dialog.FileName = string.Empty;
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txt_archivo.Text = dialog.FileName;
            LLenarGrid(txt_archivo.Text, hoja, lista);
        } 
    }

    private void LLenarGrid(string archivo, string hoja, DataGridView lista)
    {
        OleDbConnection conexion = null;
        DataSet dataSet = null;
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
        string consultaHojaExcel = "Select * from [" + hoja + "$]";
        string cadenaConexionArchivoExcel = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + archivo + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

        try
        {
            conexion = new OleDbConnection(cadenaConexionArchivoExcel);
            conexion.Open();
            dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(consultaHojaExcel, conexion);
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, hoja);
            lista.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            //validar(name, lista, layoutPanel);
            conexion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            ToastNotification.Show(this, ex.Message, global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 5000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
        }
    }
```

Consiguiendo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Pero lo que deseo también es que se cargue la imagen, como hago esto?
>   hay alguna forma de hacer esto o es imposible?

No importa si debo de cambiar todo el código si alguien realizo algo similar y me brinda su ayuda se lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿Te define la columna Imagen como un `DataGridViewImageColumn`?.

Comment: Echale un vistazo a este [enlace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cf413318-d431-4f58-af39-dc03ed847d85/import-picture-from-xls-excel-file-in-windows-app-c?forum=exceldev), te puede ser de ayuda.

Comment: @ElGerar, No, solo es un DataGridViewTextColumn

Comment: No he usado oledb para acceso a un archivo de excel pero estoy casi seguro que es mas fácil si utilizas una librería como EPPlus (que es gratuita y no requiere de tener excel instalado) o utilizar interop (que si requiere de tener excel instalado).

Comment: En este [enlace](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006240_Taking_a_Picture.html) se indica que excel mediante el _clipboard_ -portapapeles- es capaz de tomar la imagen de una celda o celdas para luego guardarla, sería ver los correspondientes comandos en c# para lograr lo que buscas y al respecto hay un blog que muestra [como usar el portapapeles con c#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/copy-cut-and-paste-parts-of-an-image-to-the-clipboard-in-c/)